# Parallel evaluation with multiple outputs in SALib package

Tags: salib

I am trying to parallelize the evaluation of the following function in salib_multi_out.py:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from model_definition import wrapped_linear
from SALib import ProblemSpec


sp = ProblemSpec(
    {
            'names': ['$\mu$','$k_1$','$k_2$', '$k_3$'],
            'bounds': [[0,0.1],[0,50],[0,1],[0,1]],
        "outputs": ["$d_{pre}$", "$d_{post}$", "$\\varepsilon$"]
    }
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    (sp.sample_sobol(2**10).evaluate(wrapped_linear).analyze_sobol(nprocs=3))
    sp.to_df()
    fig = sp.plot()
```

Where the function wrapped_linear lives in model_definition.py and contains the following:

```
def wrapped_linear(X: np.array, func=eval_func) -> np.ndarray:
    N, D = X.shape
    results = np.empty((N,3))
    for i in range(N):
        mu, k1, k2, k3 = X[i, :]
        results[i] = eval_func(mu,k1,k2,k3)
    return np.array(results)`
```

where `eval_func()` is a function that returns 3 x 1 array of outputs. I have scoured the internet on ways I could use `evaluate_parallel()` instead of `evaluate()` above, and nothing came up. The test_functions (Ishigami, lakeproblem) have been parallelized and use a method called evaluate (i.e. `Ishigami.evaluate`) for parallelization but I am not sure how to write something similar.

I tried using evaluate_parallel and it gave me the following error:
`TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`

No clue how to approach this, any help would be much appreciated.